# Vb.net how can I set Search level as user input string

Tags: vb.net

**Intro...** I've got a counter in my project that counts files in specified paths. Now all this depends on the users input as concerned would go into settings and set which extensions (`tbExt1.text`) that should be searched for as well as path (`tbpath.text`). The paths are listed in `lbchannel1` listbox. Now this wont matter too much to my question, but I filled it in so my example below is more understandable.

**Here comes the question:** The users should be able to address if its going to count TopLevelOnly (`FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly`) or TopAndSub (`FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories`).

So I made a combobox that they can select from either of those two options. When they select one of them, *FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly* or *FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories* will become the text in a textbox `tbTopOrSub1.text`

That brings me to the next part. Instead of for example *FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories* in my counter, I now added `tbTopOrSub1.text` as I hoped this would work the same way, but now be a user depended option. Have a look:

```
   Dim TopOrSub1 As String 
   TopOrSub1 = tbTopOrSub1.Text     

   Dim fileTotal As Integer
   For Each item As String In lbChannel1.Items
       fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString, TopOrSub1, (tbExt1.Text)).Count
   Next
```

I thought this would work like a charm, but it doesn't seem to work. I get this error `The converting from string FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLev to type Integer is not valid` (could be bad translation since the error was in Norwegian) and I notice how it sais TopLev. I suppose its too long? I can't figure out how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all put `Option Strict On` for your VB project. This helps alot to avoid runtime errors.

The error occurs since you try to convert a string into an enumeration (=integer).

The good thing about comboboxes is that they have a `DataSource` property which can hold a collection of objects of any type. Additionally they have the following Properties:

1. `DisplayMember`: Name of a (public) property of the object set
   in `DataSource`. The value of it will be displayed in the UI as "friendly" text.
2. `ValueMember`: Name of a property of the object set in `DataSource`. This value will not be shown in UI but you can accesss it in your code.

See my below exmaple how to use all these:

The object which holds the display text (Name) and the Value for your File Search Option:

```
 Class FileSearchOption
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Value As FileIO.SearchOption
 End Class
```

Fill your combobox and set its `DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember`:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim searchOptions As New List(Of FileSearchOption)
        searchOptions.Add(New FileSearchOption() With {.Name = "TopLevelOnly", .Value = FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly})
        searchOptions.Add(New FileSearchOption() With {.Name = "TopAndSub", .Value = FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories})

        ComboBox1.DataSource = searchOptions
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
   End Sub
```

Handle the action when the user has chosen a search option. Remark that it is necessary to DirectCast the `SelectedValue` since it is of type `Object`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim fileTotal As Integer
    For Each item As String In {"G:\"}
        fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString, DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, FileIO.SearchOption), (tbExt1.Text)).Count
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for great answer. This is probably exactly what I need. I just need some time testing, because I'm totally new to the DataSource properties for the comboboxes, so I'll dive into that. Not sure just yet how to set those properties, but I'll get to it.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x8160f6f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [there](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/programmatically-binding-datasource-to-combobox-in-multiple/) are some examples how to use DataSources.